# How can I fix this error with Wagtail CMS?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I just setup Wagtail CMS in Django and when I run `django-admin runserver` I get the following errors:

```
ERRORS:
wagtaildocs.Document.tags: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Tag', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
wagtailimages.Image.tags: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Tag', which is either not installed, or is abstract.

System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the manual you need the `taggit` library: http://wagtail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced_topics/settings.html?highlight=installed_apps#apps-settings-py

I'm guessing you forgot to install that :)

Comment: Well what I found out was that it was actually already installed, but I just forgot to put `'taggit'` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` section in my settings.py file.

Comment: Well, yes. That's part of the install process of course :) http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

So what happened was I just forgot to put `'taggit'` inside the `INSTALLED_APPS` section of my settings.py file. See the issue I submitted [here](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/issues/1383).